# Which API to use when starting with Bing Maps

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-maps

I've spent most of the Christmas reading through the Bing Maps information. However, there are so many different options and choices that I'm getting stuck on the plentifulness.

In [one of the most obvious URLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428643.aspx) I see both non-API and API approaches. That's confusing. There are AJAX, REST and Spacial Services and, to the best of my understanding, they do pretty much the same. That's confusing too...   :)

So, here's the question. I'd like to create a web page that given a certain input (e.g. XML or JSON) will provide me with an image. The image is supposed to be a map with plotted pins (that contain my descriptions), controls for zoom/pan and (preferably) even traveling routes (automatically computed or provided by me) between those pins. Also, It'd be great if I could set a semi-transparent polygons covering some areas.

Which API am I supposed to use?!

I sis something like that a few years ago with Google Maps but as far I recall, I only sent in a XML file and the map was hosted more or less at Google's.

Comment: did the link to Choose your API that is listed on the website you linked not help? http://www.microsoft.com/maps/choose-your-bing-maps-API.aspx

Comment: @AndrewCounts Partially, yes. I know it's a web app I'll develop, so I can filter the selection to the three APIs I mentioned in the question (AJAX V7, REST Services and Spacial Data Services). That's how far I get. Also, there's some talking about non-API approaches as well. All in all - confusion in my brains is total.

Comment: @KonradViltersten ew, bing.  [Yes, I know this is not a productive comment]

Comment: @JNYRanger I might be able to affect the choice of technology later on. Is Google Maps to be preferred? Or are we opening a **huge** can of worms right now? I'd prefer not to close this year by a flame war lasting to the New Year's 2014, haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're building a web site, then you'll have to choose between the AJAX Control and the REST services. Basically, the AJAX Control allows you to embedded a map in your page, add pushpins, draw shapes, display routes...etc.
See http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMap1 for a live demo.

The REST services are more useful for tasks simple like static imagery as well as requests like (reverse)geocoding and routing, that don't involve user interaction.

If you want a full "map control" that allows the user to interact with keyboard/mouse, use the AJAX API. If you're not, REST services could be enough.

---

EDIT:
AJAX API = AJAX control = AJAX v7

Spatial Data Services is a REST API that allows to compute spatial requests against a large number of data. It shouldn't be used to display a map.

If you're interested in something that allows your users to pan/zoom, create pushpins by clicking on the map...etc., then the AJAX control is the most suitable. It offers all the javascript stuff to display a dynamic map that allows user interaction.

Comment: Kick me if it's a dumb question but... Should I understand that "AJAX Control" = "AJAX V7" and "AJAX API (full map control)" = "Spacial Data Services"? At first I only need to show "static" stuff but in the long run I'd like my users to pan/zoon the map and even "click in new pins". Which API is the most suitable? I get it's the one described in the third paragraph in your great answer. But which one does it correspond to [at this URL](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/choose-your-bing-maps-API.aspx) (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file is in GeoRSS or GPX format then take a look at the modules for Bing Maps here which show you how to do this in a few lines of code: https://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/

If your XML file is a custom format then take a look at the GeoRSS module to see how to read XML in JavaScript.

If you have more than a thousand items in your XML file I would highly recommend storing your data in the Bing Spatial Data Services which will expose it as a spatial REST service, or uploading it to a database and using a web service to load the data to the map. Loading more than 1,000 pushpins to a JavaScript map could be slow. Using a service you can load only the data that is in view which would make your app much faster.